# Reverse a word in Vim

Tags: python, regex, vim

How can I reverse a word in Vim? Preferably with a regex or normal-mode commands, but other methods are welcome too:

> word => drow

Thanks for your help!
PS: I'm in windows XP

Python is built in supported in my vim, but not Perl.

Comment: I see this function very often. Exactly: why do you need that? ;)

Comment: Hi @wishi_! My girlfriend can reverse words very fast in mind and I want to check it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is another (pythonic) solution based on how this works:

```
:echo join(reverse(split('hello', '.\zs')), '')
olleh
```

If you want to replace all words in the buffer,

```
:%s/\(\<.\{-}\>\)/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(1), '.\zs')), '')/g
```

This works by first creating a list of characters in the word, which is reversed and joined back to form the word. The substitute command finds each word and then passes the word to the expressions and uses the result as replacement.

Comment: I find the method syntax easier to see where the parameters go: `'hello'->split('.\zs')->reverse()->join('')`

Answer (score 6):

This Tip might help: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_letters

It says:

Simply enable visual mode (v), highlight the characters you want inverted, and hit `\is`. For a single word you can use vw (or viw): `viw\is`

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>is :<C-U>let old_reg_a=@a<CR>
 \:let old_reg=@"<CR>
 \gv"ay
 \:let @a=substitute(@a, '.\(.*\)\@=',
 \ '\=@a[strlen(submatch(1))]', 'g')<CR>
 \gvc<C-R>a<Esc>
 \:let @a=old_reg_a<CR>
 \:let @"=old_reg<CR>
```

There are more solutions in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've got perl support built in to vim, you can do this:

```
command! ReverseWord call ReverseWord()
function! ReverseWord()
perl << EOF
    $curword = VIM::Eval('expand("<cword>")');
    $reversed = reverse($curword);
    VIM::Msg("$curword => $reversed");
    VIM::DoCommand("norm lbcw$reversed");
EOF
endfun
```

And potentially bind that to a keystroke like so:

```
nmap ,r :ReverseWord<CR>
```

Comment: Hmm, just realised that doesn't work if you're on the first letter of the word, you need to be on letter two more.

Comment: Ok, fixed it and edited my answer, basically needed norm lbcw not just bcw

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, maybe is perl no supported. But python is supported! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You can tell if you have perl with "vim --version | grep perl" if you see a "+perl" that means it's compiled in.  Most linux distos have perl built in by default although I've had to compile it in my self on win32 and macosx.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have Python supported on my VIM, but it looks like it would be pretty simple to do it with Python. [This article](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/python/soa/Extending-Vim-with-Python/0,2000064084,339283181,00.htm) seems like a good explanation of how to use Python in VIM and I'm guessing you'd do something like this:

```
:python 'word'[::-1]
```

The article indicates that the result will appear in the status bar, which would be non-optimal if you were trying to replace the string in a document, but if you just want to check that your girlfriend is properly reversing strings in her head, this should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `rev` installed (e.g. via MSys or Cygwin) then it's really not this difficult.

Select what you want to reverse and filter (`%! <cmd>`) it:

```
:%! rev
```

This pipes your selection to your shell while passing it a command.

Comment: how to reverse only selected text? How does this work : filter (`%! <cmd>`)

Answer (score 2):

*if* your version of VIM supports it you can do `vw\is` or `viw\is` (put your cursor at the first letter of the word before typing the command)... but I have had a lot of compatibility issues with that.  Not sure what has to be compiled in or turned on but this only works sometimes.

**EDIT**:

`\is` is:

```
:<C-U>let old_reg_a=@a<CR>
\ :let old_reg=@"<CR>
\ gv"ay :let @a=substitute(@a, '.\(.*\)\@=', '\=@a[strlen(submatch(1))]', 'g')<CR> 
\ gvc<C-R>a<Esc> :let @a=old_reg_a<CR> 
\ :let @"=old_reg<CR>
```

Didn't remember where it came from but a google search come this article on [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_letters).  Which shows the same thing so I guess that's it.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work for me, if you type "map", what have you got \i mapped to?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use python itself to reverse the line through the filter command. Say the text you had written was:

```
Python
```

You could reverse it by issuing.

```
:1 ! python -c "print raw_input()[::-1]"
```

And your text will be replaced to become:

```
nohtyP
```

The "1" in the command tells vi to send line 1 to the python statement which we are executing: "print raw_input()[::-1]". So if you wanted some other line reversed, you would send that line number as argument. The python statement then reverses the line of input.

Comment: This is an elegant python solution. With Thaddaeus Markle's `py3eval` solution, this becomes pretty short: `<C-r>=pyxeval("'".@a."'[::-1]")`

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to do this if you have Vim compiled with `+rightleft`. You set `'allowrevins'` which let you hit `Ctrl+_` in insert mode to start Reverse Insert mode. It was originally made for inserting bidirectional scripts.

Type your desired word in Insert mode, or move your cursor to the end of an already typed word. Hit `Ctrl+_` and then pick a completion (`i_Ctrl-x`) method which is the most likely not to return any results for your word. Ysing Ctrl+e to cancel in-place completion does not seem to work in this case.

I.e. for an unsyntactic text file you can hit in insert mode `Ctrl+x Ctrl+d` which is guaranteed to fail to find any macro/function names in the current file (See `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D` and`:h complete` for more information).

And voila! Completion lookup in reverse mode makes the looked up word  reverse. Notice that the cursor will move to the beginning of that word (it's reversed direction of writing, remember?)

You should then hit `Ctrl+_` again to get back to regular insert mode and keyboard layout and go on with editing.

*Tip:* You can set 'complete' exclusively (for the buffer, at least) to a completion option that is guaranteed to return no result. Just go over the options in `:h 'complete'`. This will make the easy `i_Ctrl-N / i_Ctrl-P` bindings available for a handy word reversal session. You can ofcourse further automate this with a macro, a function or a binding

*Note:* Setting/resetting `'paste'` and `'compatible'` can set/reset `'allowrevins'`.  See `:h allowrevins`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some time on your hands, you can bubble your way there by iteratively transposing characters (`xp`)...

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the game, but I thought I'd just add what I think is the simplest method.

It's two things:

- Vim's expression register
- `pyeval` (`py3eval` on recent vim releases) function

So to reverse a word you would do the following:

- `"ayiw` yank word into register `a`
- `<C-r>=py3eval('"".join(reversed(str(' . @a ')))')` use vim's `=` (expression) register to call the `py3eval` function which evaluates python code (duh) and returns the result, which is then fed via the expression register into our document.

For more info on the expression register see https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/#the-expression-and-the-search-registers

Comment: `py3eval` is a great idea! With Rohit's python solution, this becomes a bit shorter: `<C-r>=pyxeval("'".@a."'[::-1]")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `revins` mode in order to do it:

at the beginning type `:set revins`. from now on every letter you type will be inserted in a reverse order, until you type `:set norevins` to turn off. i.e, while `revins` is set, typing `word` will output `drow`.

in order to change an existing word after `revins` mode is set, and the cursor on beginning of the word, type:

`dwi<C-r>"<ESC>`

explanation:

- `dw` deleted a word.
- `i` to enter insert mode
- `<C-r>"` to paste the last deleted or yaked text in insert mode, `<ESC>` to exit insert mode.

remember to `:set norevins` at the end!

Answer (score 0):

After years I stumbled over my question and had an idea.
Here a solution with only vim's ex-commands.

Buffer with a line with only one word:

```
s/\(.\)/\1\r/g
g/^/ move 0
%join!
```

Buffer with a line with many words separated through space:

```
s/$/ /
s/\</\r/g
g/^/m 0
%s/\(.\)/\1\r/g
g/^/m 0
%join!
s/^ //
```

Explanation for the solution for many words:

1. Add Space to the end
2. Break line: each word in one line
3. Reverse order of lines (words)
4. Break words: each character in one line
5. Reverse order of lines (characters)
6. Join lines
7. Delete space at front