# Hexstring reversal in vim

Tags: vim

I have an hex string as shown below.

```
x"fedcba9876543210"
```

How do i change it reverse it like as below using vim commands.

```
x"01234567890abcdef"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680194/reverse-a-word-in-vim.

In short, `viw\is`.

Answer (score 4):

Some tips from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_selected_text

one way:

```
vnoremap ;rv c<C-O>:set revins<CR><C-R>"<Esc>:set norevins<CR>
```

another:

```
" \fr: reverse the order of lines (vertical mirror)
nmap \fr :set lz<CR>o<Esc>mz'aO<Esc>ma:'a+1,'z-1g/^/m 'a<CR>'addma'zdd:set nolz<CR>

" \fR: mirror image the lines (horizontal mirror)
nmap \fR :set lz<CR>o<Esc>mzkO<Esc>maj:s/./&\r/g<CR>:'a+1,'z-1g/^/m 'a<CR>:'a+1,'z-1j!<CR>'add'zddk:set nolz<CR>
```

a third:

```
nmap \fR :Mirror<CR>
command! -bar -range Mirror <line1>,<line2>call setline('.', join(reverse(split(getline('.'), '\zs')), ''))
```